# $_POST not inserting into database - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, post, insert

Here is my HTML form for adding data into the table:

```
<div class="TTWForm-container">
<div id="form-title" class="form-title field"><h2>ახალი სტატია</h2></div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php?link=addart" class="TTWForm ui-sortable-disabled" method="post"> 
<div id="field2-container" class="field f_100 ui-resizable-disabled ui-state-disabled">
<label for="title">სათაური</label>
<input name="title" id="title" required="required" type="text">
</div>
<div id="field10-container" class="field f_100 ui-resizable-disabled ui-state-disabled">
<label for="post">
სტატია
</label>
<textarea rows="15" cols="40" name="post" id="post" required="required"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="form-submit" class="field f_100 clearfix submit">
<input value="დამატება" type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

processing

```
if (isset($_POST['title'])) {$title = $_POST['title'];}
if (isset($_POST['post'])) {$post = $_POST['post'];}

<?php
if (isset($title) && isset($post))
{
/*can add post */
$insert = "INSERT INTO article ('title','post') VALUES ('$title','$post')";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$insert);

if ($result == 'true') {echo "<p>post is added.</p>";}
else {echo "<p>post is not added.</p>";}
}
else
{
echo "<p>Fill all fields.</p>";
}
?>
```

After processing it always says that post is not added. Checking database and  its true. Cant find the mistake. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: seeing your label, i wonder what encoding type you try to save in your database. did you use the right encoding for your mysql table?

Comment: Checking the error logs on your server might be a good start...

Comment: I use UTF8_general_ci for storing Georgian characters. Stored data is Georgian.

Comment: I use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the begining of php file. and page diplays no error.

Comment: Do this `$result = mysqli_query($connect,$insert) or die(mysqli_error($connect));` and you will see SQL errors. I also don't see why you're using `if (isset($title) && isset($post))` you're already doing that.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections; you should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: @Gumbo Not "yet" lol - When the code starts to work, yes ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You’re already able to inject arbitrary SQL code, although you can’t do anything to make it valid.

Comment: @Gumbo I agree, but how would it make it past `('title','post')` if OP is treating those as strings instead of columns?

Comment: @Fred-ii- As I said, nothing you may inject would make it valid. So I should rather have use 'prone' instead of 'vulnerable'. ;-)

Comment: @Gumbo No argument there ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so just change:

```
else
{
echo "<p>post is not added</p>";
}
```

to:

```
else
{
echo "<p>MySQL error:".mysqli_error($connect)."</p>";
}
```

Comment: Log the errors, but don’t print them. This will most likely make it into production code and may reveal sensitive internal information only meant for the developer.

Comment: I think @David was asking about help how to debug his code and to find what is wrong. not about how to create good application.

Comment: I prefer to do one thing one step, if you don't - provide your answer, with all best prectice and bind params, bin result, go ahead. why do you prefer to comment my answer but not the original question? just flooding?

Comment: TBH, this is more fit to be a comment. Go over the OP's code again very carefully. There are more important mistakes made that need to be tended to. As stated under OP's question and a few of the answers given.

Comment: Thanks @KimAlexander. After using given instruction i found error. using single quotes was mistake here => `$insert = "INSERT INTO article ('title','post')...";`

Comment: comment is very difficult to read with fragment of code, so when I do reply with more then 10-20 characters of code I prefer to do Answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a prepared statement for you.

```
$link = new MySQLi('localhost','username','password','database');

if(isset($_POST['title'],$_POST['post'])&& $_POST['title'] !="" && $_POST['post'] !=""){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $post = $_POST['post'];
        if($query = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO article (title,post) VALUES(?,?)')){
            $query->bind_param('ss',$title,$post);
            $query->execute();
            $query->close();
            echo 'Success!';
        }else{
            echo 'Failure!';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'You missed a field!';
}
```

Comment: Noble, but you should have fixed the errors in the other answer you gave, and modify it with this one instead.

Comment: I was already working on a prepared statement for the lad. Seemed pointless. @Fred-ii-

Comment: I actually didn't catch that error prior, so good eye on that. @Fred-ii-

Comment: One gets used to it after a while ;-)

Comment: I've been a developer for 5 years, and do this for a living. It's just a thing that happens once in a while. But please, upvote my new answer ;) @Fred-ii-

Comment: That's indeed a compliment, thanks; especially that I've been raised on DOS 5.0 and Win 3.1 and XP computers with a whole 20 mb HD and 256 massive K's of RAM ;-)

Comment: Mmmmm can you taste the *quality* ;) @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 1):

**Boolean Comparison**

First, check your comparison. `mysqli_query` returns a boolean `true` or `false`, not a string 'true' or 'false.' Instead of:

```
if ($result == 'true')
```

use

```
if ($result == true)
```

or even:

```
if ($result)
```

**Debug the Query**

Next, check the query itself for errors. As Fred [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012253/php-mysql-post-not-inserting-into-database/28012290#comment44411911_28012290), you should mark your column names with back ticks instead of single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO article (`title`,`post`)
```

Consider logging the output of mysqli_error, or try echoing your query and run it manually against the database. You may find that they query has a hidden syntax or data error that is not obvious in the code.

**Posted Values**

Next, check the values that you are fetching from `$_POST`. Is `$_POST['post']` set? Does it have a useful value?

**Database Connection**

Finally, check the database connection itself. Are you truly connected? Do you have debugging logging or output around the connection attempt?

Comment: Plus, the OP is treating their columns as values `('title','post')`

Comment: I personally think OP accepted the wrong answer. This covers pretty much everything.